# Remote access to `/dev/input` fails with permission error

Tags: ssh, remote-access, usb, sshfs, udev

I need to open a USB game controller device (joystick) remotely. This device is physically connected to server and is available for local user with permissions:

```
crw-rw-r--+ 1 root input 13, 0 ** /dev/input/js0
```

Using `sshfs` on client side, I mounted remote `/dev/input/` on a local folder `/dev/input/remote/`:

```
sudo sshfs -o allow_other server-usr@server_ip:/dev/input /dev/input/remote
```

Now, I can see the device in mounted folder on client:

```
crw-rw-r-- 1 root netdev 0, 0 ** /dev/input/remote/js0
```

However, programs on client side (like `jstest`) fail to open/use device with **Permission Denied** error!

**How can I find access to remote Joystick on the client without permission issues?**

MORE: users on both sides are added to `FUSE` and `NETDEV` groups. Also, I have added line `user_allow_other` to `/etc/fuse.conf` which is required for `allow_other` argument in SSHFS command. Changing `chmod` for the device to `777` didn't help as well. No success.

Comment: I doubt that sshfs will "forward" ioctl() made on devices, because SFTP certainly wouldn't have an command called IOCTL in its API. It's working on filesystems, not char devices. See also https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/CUSE.html , https://superuser.com/questions/209884/where-are-programs-that-use-cuse-character-in-user-space

Comment: This would give you better success: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/usb/usbip_protocol.html

Comment: @A.B Thanks, I tried `usbip`, it works on older kernels which my machine doesn't support. I installed it via `linux-tools-generic` and followed the instruction here: https://developer.ridgerun.com/wiki/index.php?title=How_to_setup_and_use_USB/IP, my client fails to find and mount `usbip` and `vhci-hcd` modules using `sudo modprobe`. I also tried `socat`+`ser2net` to pipe traffic. However, joystick does not work as normal `UART` device and traffic from pipe is not decoded correctly.